# String split exception

Tags: java, string

I have a simple code which split a string buffer object which is separated by comma. But it gives me a exception when doing it?

```
Method "toString" with signature "()Ljava/lang/String;" is not
  applicable on this object
```

### Code

```
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
sb.append("a,b,c");     
String [] str = sb.toString().split(","); //gives the exception
```

I am using java 1.4 in this project.

Comment: *"I am using java 1.4 in this project."*  Why target an obsolete version?

Comment: What kind of java is this? Does not look like Oracle. toString is an Object method.

Comment: A search for this error on Stackoverflow and on Google gives a few instances related to development on Blackberry. Is this what you are working for ? I ask that because I think we need more context here.

Comment: no its just a normal java application with struts 1

Comment: im using java 1.4 because the system was build on that and im doing enhancements for it

Comment: What's the result of the command `java --version`?

Answer (score 0):

The same code executes without any error, the stringbuffer.append(String) and split(regex) are from java 1.4 itself. Although if you are trying this stringbuffer.append(CharSequence) then it may give error.